# using accelerometer to determine if phone is at rest

Tags: windows-phone-7, accelerometer

I'm building an app using the Windows Phone 7 SDK and I've got a thread that is constantly returning X, Y, and Z accelerometer data.  I need to determine at any given time whether the phone is moving or not.  Can someone help me step through the logic/math needed for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [high-pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter#Algorithmic_implementation). Chose an alpha arbitrarily (0.3 seems as a good initial guess),  and if `y[i]` exceeds a threshold determined by your experiments then the phone is moving, otherwise it is not. Note that you only need to store the last `y[i]` and the last measurement. Good luck!